# Does "goodly" in this sentence in Hamlet mean "considerable" or "pleasing?

Tags: meaning, early-modern-english, shakespeare

In Hamlet there is the following conversation:

> GUILDENSTERN: *Prison, my lord!*
>
> HAMLET: *Denmark's a prison.*
>
> ROSENCRANTZ: *Then is the world one.*
>
> HAMLET: *A **goodly** one; in which there are many confines,
>         wards and dungeons, Denmark being one o' the worst.*

What does "goodly" mean here? After consulting some [dictionaries](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/goodly), I tend to think it means "considerable", "grand" in a sense of scale. However, I encountered an Italian translation  ([Google](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%C3%88+una+bella+prigione,+il+mondo) returns more than 500,000 entries for this search) which says

> "È una bella prigione, il mondo",

It basically means "the world is a beautiful prison", which interprets "goodly" in the sense of "pleasing".

Is this just simply a mistranslation or might "goodly" also have this meaning here?

Comment: First of all, *bello/a* means a lot more than *beautiful*, so it's unproductive to go through Italian to get to the English meaning. Second, you should use a Shakespearean dictionary  such as [Shakespeare’s Words](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Glossary?let=g) (modern dictionaries are going to concentrate on modern definitions); third, a very good edition of the individual work in question will be one that has an extensive commentary including explanations of words and phrases.

Comment: @Clare Well I don't think I intended to "go through Italian to get to the English meaning" anyways. I just saw that sentence in Italian and thought it looked a bit weird. I traced it down to the original sentence and thus had the question. If somebody on this site has the reference/knows the answer already, fine; if not, I'm not going to lose sleep over this or likely to spend the energy to go and get an extensive edition of Hamlet just to satisfy a bit of curiosity and skepticism.

Comment: If you're not that interested in obtaining an answer, then why post the question? You can find several good commentaries of Hamlet on Google Books. This site is for serious and enthusiastic folks; if you have little enthusiasm (only "bit of curiosity")  I'm not sure you should post a question.

Comment: @Clare Are you here to start a fight with everybody or what? What's wrong with me asking this question on this site yet having no interest to spend an hour or something trying to find a copyrighted book which might well cost me more time and even money? If everybody solves their questions by looking at references themselves, why is this site ever here? Why are you ever here? Just to be picky about others?

Comment: I don't think a high level of enthusiasm is a requirement. The point is to ask questions that benefit the site as a whole, which I think this will.

Comment: @Clare - una bella prigione means a beautiful prison.

Comment: @Clare Anyways, if you think there's any problem with this question, just flag it and ask the mods to deal with it. Let's see what they think. If not, then please just stop posting comments which don't contribute anything to the question itself, and which might even seem hostile. I have no time for such meaningless discussion about "enthusiasm" or whatnot. And of course I have enthusiasm to start with so that I asked this question. Otherwise why did I even bother to write so much stuff? You're really in a bad mood today aren't you?

Comment: I'm in a bel mood.

Comment: Goodly in the sense of extensive is often used before words that can be quantified, such as sum and amount, as per the examples in Collins. Thus, it means 'a good number of'. Goodly is basically the word *good* with an -ly stuck to it. You can often remove the -ly and get one meaning of goodly  namely, good (as in good quality). When applied to people  and also to things, good quality is often equated with 'good looking'. And goodly=extensive can also carry an admixture of meaning with goodly=good/fine. Just like good can be used to mean multiple things, often at once, so can goodly.

Comment: So  trying to pin down an exact meaning may not be possible (this is what often gets scholars in troubleñ they build theories based on a single interpretation when more than one is possible, even plausible) and Shakespeare is known for playing on multiple meanings. Even Shakespeare's Words (link elsewhere) only suggests meanings. One has to read a lot of Shakespeare to know Shakespeare. Here he doesn't say 'a goodly prison' but 'a goodly one'. Does 'a goodly one'  describe prison or world or both? It's the world as a metaphor for a prison. As such  it's a goodly one' and Shakespeare goes on to

Comment: list some characteristics: 'in which there are many confines, wards and dungeons'. I don't think the quantitative sense is the primary one, but  a fine/quality prison can also be a large one. Then there is the word 'confines' which is a sort of opposite of extensive, yet here it also means 'cells'. So there's something going on with confines. And probably also with goodly. Basically the world is a good/fine/beautiful/possibly extensive prison, for multiple reasons  some of which are explicitly named.

Comment: @Clare comments have a *badly* habit of being deleted or shifted to chat. Why not copy and paste these pertinent and helpful reflections and make it into an answer? The answer being, if I've understood correctly,  "No one really knows because ....".

Comment: As for telling/advising/recommending that the OP to brush up on his Shakespeare, when all he really wants to know is the word *goodly* used in one line, seems a bit excessive. The OP has done more research, showing his keenness, than 70% of the questions that are posted here.

Answer (score 11):

Although *goodly* at this point means "of considerable size", this was **not** the meaning that Shakespeare intended. Goodly has quite a few other archaic and rare definitions. I believe the Italian translation was accurate, and the intended (now archaic) sense was:

> Of good or pleasing appearance; handsome, beautiful, good-looking; comely, fair.
>   <sub>[OED](http://www.oed.com) (the premium version, since the [free](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/goodly) version is too brief)</sub>

Comment: Yeah, even though one is tempted to define it as "yuge", likely what Shaky meant was basically "good", with a bit of emphasis.

Comment: I stand corrected. I had always thought Hamlet was saying that the world was a prison of "sufficient means." The notion that it was a pleasing, beautiful prison never came to mind.

Comment: I don’t quite follow this answer — *why* do you feel that this is what Shakespeare intended?  Is there a reason why you feel the reading with “good” fits the context better, or a source that in Shakespeare’s time “good” was the more common meaning?  Since the reading with “large” seems to make just as much sense, and “large” is by the more common meaning of “goodly”, I feel this answer needs some kind of justification.

Comment: From the context "large" makes more sense to me. The next sentence talks about the many countries the world contains. It contrast the "big prison" (the world) with the small prison (Denmark). So like @PLL I'd like to see some evidence that your interpretation is what the author intended. (And of course there is always the possibility of deliberate ambiguity)

Comment: The online Oxford dictionary is not a "free version" of the OED. In addition, you have picked out one meaning of *goodly* given in the OED and given no justification beyond your opinion.

Comment: -1 for cherry picking. The OED ***also*** contains the definition "*Notable or considerable in respect of size, quantity, or number; fairly large, sizeable.*" Both definitions are attested to in Shakespeare's time.

Answer (score 6):

In day-to-day talk, goodly means sizable or large. Like "I drank a goodly amount of orange juice, and I now feel sick." Since the world is much larger than Denmark and in the story is described as having "many confines", then goodly in this instance would most likely also mean large. I'm assuming the Italian version was just a mistranslation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What support do you have for this? Is it just an opinion or a fact-based answer?

Comment: I know what goodly means, and I did a quick Google search to confirm that I had the correct meaning. Also, from the way Hamlet says that Denmark is a dungeon in Earth's prison pretty much confirms that he is saying that Earth is large. This is pretty much based on my knowledge of English.

Comment: That's irrelevant. This site is a resource site, meaning the content on here is meant to help more than just the OP. If someone stumbled upon your answer, they will be less likely to take it seriously because it's just an opinion. Answers that provide links in support of their opinions will be more credible. How are we supposed to know you did't just make it all up. My point is, provide sources and links to backup your opinions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Hank! I was just trying to give a quick input, but in future I'll try provide better sources for my answers and do a bit more research.

Comment: I hope I didn't come off crass. Just helping out for current and future answers :)

Comment: I have to say that there are times when an opinion is all that counts. Not everything can be googled, thank God. And I agree with this answer.

Comment: Some support for your answer: According to the OED, both *sizable* and *handsome* were possible meanings for *goodly* in Shakespeare's time (and a century or two earlier, as well).

Answer (score 4):

The OED says that both *sizable* and *handsome* were possible meanings for *goodly* in Shakespeare's time, so the 16th century meaning of the word does not help.

We can look for help to other translations of *Hamlet*, and we discover that there is considerable support among these for the *sizable* meaning. As some of the comments speculate, it's quite possible that Shakespeare meant the word to carry both meanings.

The [*No Fear Shakespeare*](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/hamlet/page_106.html) supports the "sizable" meaning. It "translates" this passage as:

> Hamlet: Denmark’s a prison.
>   Rosencrantz: Then I guess the whole world is one.
>   Hamlet: Yes, quite a large one, with many cells and dungeons,  Denmark being one of the worst.

The [French translation](https://lirenligne.net/livre/William%20SHAKESPEARE/Hamlet/538) of Hamlet also supports the "sizable" meaning. It translates this passage as:

> HAMLET. − Le Danemark est une prison.
>   ROSENCRANTZ. − Alors le monde en est une aussi.
>   HAMLET. − Une ***vaste*** prison, dans laquelle il y a beaucoup de cellules, de cachots et de donjons. Le Danemark est un des pires. [emphasis added]

The French word *vaste* means *vast*.

The [German translation](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/7276/pg7276.html) manages to avoid the problem by choosing the word *stattlich*, which can mean *impressive, imposing* or *handsome*.

> Hamlet.
>   Dännemark ist ein Kerker.
>   Rosenkranz.
>   So ist die ganze Welt einer.
>   Hamlet.
>   Ein recht stattlicher, worinn viele Thürme, Gefängnisse und Löcher sind, unter denen Dännemark eines der ärgsten ist.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/goodly

goodly
adjective

```
1 Considerable in size or quantity: ‘a goodly number of our countrymen’

2 archaic Attractive, excellent, or admirable.
```

I'd suggest that in this sense it takes the archaic meaning "excellent" - and I'd dispute the allegation of `archaic`...